# Unable to mount Kindle on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, lenovo, kindle, nexus-10

Upon connecting my kindle, nautilus opens up for just a second and then flashes a message saying that kindle is unavailable. Then there are a host of messages on dmesg about device not accepting set address.

Here is the excerpt from my /var/log/syslog

```
Oct 24 21:23:30 ideapad kernel: [   74.381463] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
Oct 24 21:23:30 ideapad kernel: [   74.486518] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1949, idProduct=0004
Oct 24 21:23:30 ideapad kernel: [   74.486523] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct 24 21:23:30 ideapad kernel: [   74.486526] usb 1-1.3: Product: Amazon Kindle
Oct 24 21:23:30 ideapad kernel: [   74.486528] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Amazon
Oct 24 21:23:30 ideapad kernel: [   74.486530] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: B00F260714741NTS
Oct 24 21:23:30 ideapad mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Oct 24 21:23:30 ideapad mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Oct 24 21:23:30 ideapad kernel: [   74.521970] usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Oct 24 21:23:30 ideapad kernel: [   74.522030] scsi2 : usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
Oct 24 21:23:30 ideapad kernel: [   74.522101] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Oct 24 21:23:31 ideapad kernel: [   75.523700] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kindle   Internal Storage 0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Oct 24 21:23:31 ideapad kernel: [   75.523969] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Oct 24 21:23:31 ideapad kernel: [   75.533767] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Oct 24 21:23:33 ideapad kernel: [   77.776542] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 6754304 512-byte logical blocks: (3.45 GB/3.22 GiB)
Oct 24 21:23:33 ideapad kernel: [   77.990710] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Oct 24 21:23:33 ideapad kernel: [   78.211689]  sdb: sdb1
Oct 24 21:23:34 ideapad kernel: [   78.984869] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
Oct 24 21:23:34 ideapad udisksd[2782]: Mounted /dev/sdb1 at /media/anuvrat/Kindle on behalf of uid 1000
Oct 24 21:23:34 ideapad dbus[1155]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' (using servicehelper)
Oct 24 21:23:34 ideapad kernel: [   79.084417] systemd-hostnamed[3165]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
Oct 24 21:23:34 ideapad dbus[1155]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Oct 24 21:23:39 ideapad kernel: [   83.393011] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 6
Oct 24 21:23:39 ideapad kernel: [   83.395618] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Oct 24 21:23:39 ideapad kernel: [   83.395661] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  
Oct 24 21:23:39 ideapad kernel: [   83.395664] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Oct 24 21:23:39 ideapad udisksd[2782]: Cleaning up mount point /media/anuvrat/Kindle (device 8:17 no longer exist)
Oct 24 21:23:39 ideapad kernel: [   83.593023] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
Oct 24 21:23:39 ideapad kernel: [   83.848936] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
Oct 24 21:23:40 ideapad kernel: [   84.612888] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
Oct 24 21:23:40 ideapad kernel: [   84.868872] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
Oct 24 21:23:41 ideapad kernel: [   85.636833] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 15 using ehci-pci
Oct 24 21:23:41 ideapad kernel: [   86.148801] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
```

PS: I am facing similar issues with my nexus5 and an EVDO data card.

update #01: mtpfs is already installed.

update #02: It doesn't work on Lenovo S510 running ubuntu 14.04 but works on Lenovo Z50.

Answer (score 37):

I had the same problem and it turned out that I used a charge-only USB cable (Stupid me!). Worth mentioning, though, I guess...

Comment: This answer helped me to find out the problem and solve it immediately.

Comment: This is definitely worth trying first. On Ubuntu 19.10, I only needed the right data-capable cable.

Comment: Oh... didn't knew suck things existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This command could help :

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs    
sudo apt-get install calibre
```

Comment: the device is not showing up as a storage medium, would calibre help?

Comment: It should fix. Can you try and update?

Comment: mtpfs was installed and I installed calibre too. Problem still exists. :(

Comment: Installing mtpfs actually solved the problem. I don't understand why this answer has been downvoted

Answer (score 1):

In my case this is specific to older Kindles (OS 4.x). The only solution was to unplug the cable from my USB hub and directly attach it to my computer. Again, newer 5.x Kindles work fine with a USB hub.

Let me also link to related Stack Overflow posts that might help someone else:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257201/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151527/

Answer (score -1):

I had something similar. When I connect my Kindle paper-white I get a message:

```
unable to mount
```

I click OK & it goes. But then I click on the folder thing in list of icons on the left of the desktop & navigate to the Kindle, I can see & access all the files there. So it has mounted! I have Ubuntu 14.04 on my Comp.

Have fun.

d0m.